# MEAN stack- How do I allow API access to only logged in(email/password and Facebook Login) users

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, authentication, oauth, passport.js

I have been reading online for a whole day now and found all the solutions to be partial and not to the point.

I have an API written in node and express -(/api/plans/) and (api/users/). Currently, I have been able to implement functionality for a simple email and password signup and login. If the user is successfully logged in, I generate a token on the node server and send it back to the Angular Front end. But my API is accessible without any authentication and I want to change that.

I want to restrict API access to only my front end(Angular) users who are logged in. Also, for the users to sign up/login, besides giving a simple email and password signup, which I already have, I want to give a single sign on with Facebook as well.

I was thinking of using passport-facebook strategy, which will give me the facebook access token, but I am lost as to  how I can integrate facebook access token with the email/password token I am generating right now and then how I can use the tokens to protect my API endpoints to only logged in users.

Looking for suggestions, on how to best go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) to secure your api. make a route that match all the request to your api `app.use('/api', apiRoutes);`. Then in this file do something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var route = express.Router();
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

route.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
  // here check if the user is log in (use params from the 'req' object)
  // and generate a token with jwt

  // find the user
  User.findOne({
      username: req.body.name
  }, function(err, user) {

      if (err) throw err;

      if (!user) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
      } else {

        // check if password matches
        if (user.password != req.body.password) {
          res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.' });
        } else {

          // if user is found and password is right
          // create a token
          var token = jwt.sign(user, process.env.superSecret, {
            expiresInMinutes: 1440 // expires in 24 hours
          });

          // return the information including token as JSON
          res.json({
            success: true,
            message: 'Enjoy your token!',
            token: token
          });
        }

      }
  });
}
// TODO: route middleware to verify a token
route.use(function(req, res, next) {

    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    // decode token
    if (token) {

        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.superSecret, function(err, decoded) {
          if (err) {
            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });
          } else {
            // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
            req.decoded = decoded;
            next();
          }
        });

    } else {

        // if there is no token
        // return an error
        return res.status(403).send({
            success: false,
            message: 'No token provided.'
        });
    }
});

// route to show a random message (GET http://localhost:3000/api/)
route.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.json({ message: 'Welcome to the coolest API on earth!' });
});


module.exports = route;
```

You can use a passport-facebook strategy or your own local strategy without distinction. All you need is a mechanism in order to verify if the user is login when he is trying to get access to the api.

Comment: please accept the answer if you think that is correct for you.